# How to detect polygon edge when implementing a plane sweep algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, triangulation

I am working in javascript and trying to implement an algorithm that triangulates a polygon  (something convex or concave but assumed to be a simple polygon, not self crossing and without holes).

I have found a solution on the web but it is only in pseudocode and I am trying to implement it. ( source of the algorithm : [https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Triangulation.pdf](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Esuri/cs235/Triangulation.pdf) page 19).
The first step is to partition the polygon into trapezoids with a plane sweep algorithm, which is described as "At each vertex, extend vertical line until it hits a polygon edge. Each face of this decomposition is a trapezoid; which may degenerate into a triangle."

Considering that my polygon is set of coordinates, how do I know that my line is crossing the polygon ?

I was thinking that I could do something like

1. take the horinzontal x coordinate of my vertex as x1
2. take each pair of sucessive vertices (x2, y2, x3, y3)
3. test if they are on each side of the line (x2 < x1 and x1 < x3 or the opposite)
4. if yes calculate the equation for the line between them
5. use this equation to calculate y1

but it sounds like overkill since it has a O(n²) complexity and the pseudocode announces O(n*log(n)). And I can't stop when I have found a solution since my polygone might "double back" and there would be multiple points of crossing.

Is there another way to find the points where the line crosses the polygon?
(Or a simple way to triangulate the polygon in the first place)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066287/how-to-find-the-intersect-points-in-a-polygon-object) help?

Comment: I don't think it helps.
From my understanding, the answer you linked is using the same method than the one I am trying to replace, except they have two sets of finite lines instead of one set of finite lines and one set of infinite vertical lines defined by a point.
Thank you anyway

Comment: On page 23 of the referenced `Triangulation.pdf`, the first step involves sorting the vertices of the polygon from left to right.  Thus, a binary search can be used to find the polygon line segments that are crossed by the vertical line.  A binary search is O( log n )...

Answer (score 0):

There might be easier ways to solve it, but this might be one approach:

Make use of the [Bentley Ottman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) for finding intersections in a set of line segments. Since your polygon is not self-intersecting, you can just add your sweep segments and find its intersections in *O((n + k) log n)* time, where *k* is the number of intersections. As long as the total number of intersections is *O(n)* (which will be the case if your polygon is not too crazy shaped), the resulting time complexity should be *O(n log n)*.